# Creating a shortcode from a backend page

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, wp-admin

I am trying to create a shortcode from a page that currently resides in the back end. The page has several acf fields as part of a form that creates a request. I would now like to have the same page on the front end. I have tried following the syntax of creating a shortcode from a function after reading about shortocdes, its api and doc and several different tuts online.

```
add_shortcode('create_requests', array($this, 'load_custom_wp_admin_style'));
```

^ The attempt above didn't work and I don't get any output when I include the shortcode in a new page.

You can notice that the function I am trying to use 'load_custom_wp_admin_style' returns a null value and uses hooks.

[This](https://eval.in/private/d1b29d97dc9650) is the file that contains the function.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include file like below code. I checked your file according to me you need use the plugin url it seems like you are developing the plugin

```
wp_register_style('your_namespace', plugins_url('style.css',__FILE__ ));
wp_enqueue_style('your_namespace');
wp_register_script( 'your_namespace', plugins_url('your_script.js',__FILE__ ));
wp_enqueue_script('your_namespace');
```

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. The page works just fine in wp-admin on the backend. What I'm failing to accomplish is create a shortcode and include it in a new wordpress page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the page you want to display on the front end is a normal WordPress page - created in the pages tab, post type page.

Very simply you can just use the following PHP code to include it in a template:

```
<?php
$page = get_post(192994);
echo $page->post_content;
?>
```

If it needs to be a shortcode you can add this into your functions.php:

```
function output_page_function($atts) {
    $page_id = $atts['page_id'];

    if (!$page_id) return false;

    $page = get_post($page_id);

    return $page->post_content;
}
add_shortcode('output_page', 'output_page_function');
```

And include a shortcode where desired (with 'page_id' attribute)

```
[output_page page_id=192994]
```

If it's not a WordPress page, but an actual wp-admin screen, then this would be significantly more difficult/not possible.

Comment: It is a wp-admin screen which contains a form that has several acf fields and a submit button.